# PostgreSQL: How to scroll up in long output

Tags: postgresql, psql, putty, pager

Say I get a large query back.  Postgres gives me the `--More--` indicator.  Pressing `<space>` moves down a page.  Pressing `<enter>` moves down a line.  Is there a way to scroll back up?  Is it possible to pipe the output to something like `less`?

I'm accessing PostgreSQL 9.5 on CentOS7 through PuTTY.

For example:

```
pundb=# \x on
pundb=# select * from pg_roles;

-[ RECORD 1 ]--+-------------
rolname        | dinner
rolsuper       | t
rolinherit     | t
rolcreaterole  | t
rolcreatedb    | t
rolcanlogin    | t
rolreplication | t
rolconnlimit   | -1
rolpassword    | ********
rolvaliduntil  |
rolbypassrls   | t
rolconfig      |
oid            | 10
-[ RECORD 2 ]--+-------------
rolname        | sushi
rolsuper       | f
rolinherit     | t
rolcreaterole  | f
rolcreatedb    | f
rolcanlogin    | t
rolreplication | f
rolconnlimit   | -1
rolpassword    | ********
rolvaliduntil  |
rolbypassrls   | f
rolconfig      |
oid            | 16384
-[ RECORD 3 ]--+-------------
rolname        | drum
rolsuper       | f
rolinherit     | t
rolcreaterole  | f
rolcreatedb    | f
--More--
```

**EDIT:** I know that `h` takes me to the help.  It says

> b or ctrl-B             Skip backwards k screenfuls of text [1]

but this does not work.  Maybe because I'm in PuTTY?

Comment: Tragically mine seems to be "only down" as will (linux).  Must be some kind of forward only paging?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably using a `$PAGER` that doesn't support scrolling upwards. E.g. `more`.

Try executing postgresql client using a different PAGER variable:

```
PAGER=less psql [...]
```

Or:

```
export PAGER=less
psql [...]
```

If you want to make the change permanent, insert the above `export` line into your `~/.bash_profile`.

Note: This will affect many things that use the `$PAGER` environment variable, but hey, it'll only enhance the experience right?

Comment: If you want to scroll horizontally, use `PAGER="less -S" psql [...]`

Answer (score 2):

The `--More--` indicator in the lower-left corner suggests that you're using the default pager [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)), which doesn't allow backward movement. You can switch to [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) from inside `psql` using this command:

```
\setenv PAGER 'less'
```

BTW, setting the pager to `less -S` (or typing `-S` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside `less`) will allow you to scroll sideways without wrapping (thus making the expanded mode unnecessary). And if you want to go fancy, you could use [`pspg`](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) :)